# Performing Userform Initialize with MultiPage

Tags: excel, vba, initialization, userform, multipage

Is there a way to run a userform initialize with multipage that pertains to each page separately?

I have a MultiPage Userform with Checkboxes, ComboBoxes, and TextBoxes on each sheet with different control sources for each. Instead of programming each checkbox, I have been using a userform initialize to add the checkboxes, however this does not appear to work with multipage.

I have attempted to use an if statement to specify which page to initialize, but this does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim Left As Single, Top As Single
    Dim cell As Range, row As Range, check As MSForms.CheckBox
     Top = 54
     Left = 29
   'Element Deficiency Matrix (1a to 3k)
    If MultiPage1.Value = 0 Then
       With Worksheets("Pier Data2")
          For Each row In .Range("A122:K124").Rows
             For Each cell In row.Cells
                Set check = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1")
                With check
                   .ControlSource = "'" & cell.Parent.Name & "'!" & cell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                   .Left = Left
                   .Top = Top
                   .Width = 12.6
                   .Height = 17.6
                   Left = Left + 12
                End With
            Next
          Left = 29
          Top = Top + 17.6
          Width = Width
        Next
   End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set check = Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Add ("Forms.Checkbox.1")`

Comment: Wow, Thank you. Such an easy fix! I had something similar earlier, but must have missed something!